# Finding least commonly occurring fuzzy string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, search, fuzzy-search

I've got a 10K+ line log file that I'm using to debug an issue. I'm looking for 'aberrant' log lines that occur infrequently relative to the other lines in the file to hopefully extract interesting happenings that may be occurring. These log lines are highly variable and diverse.

My initial approach was to do a fuzzy comparison of each line against the remaining lines in the file, get an average of those ratios and assign it to each line, sort those ratios and return the smallest N items in that set.

However, this takes a very, very long time on my machine when using Python (I'm using fuzzywuzzy).

Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: hard to know without seeing examples, but iterate over each line and fuzzy compare to the previous. If it is similar enough, consider them to be of same type and cluster them (erase one). This will hopefully give you much less clusters to work with when comparing all against all.

Comment: Ah -- so your decisions of what is important is based only on similarity between lines?  If so, my answer won't be useful to you.  You need a pass of machine learning to extract the necessary differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that comparison, make one pass of the file to categorize the lines by their distinctive features.  Store a reference to each line in a dict, keyed by category.

Then make a pass over the dict, eliminating any keys with too many references (i.e. boring categories).  The remaining categories are the interesting ones.

This is an **O(N)** process, rather than the **O(N^2)** process with which you started.

Comment: I don't know the list of distinctive features a-priori - the logs lines are analogous to a kernel syslog, very varied in their formatting, a mix of numbers, text.

Just tokenizing by words would be a poor approach and unlikely to yield results, since it's a unique sentence I'm looking for.